# Tell if ansible playbook is being run directly

Tags: ansible

I've got a monolithic playbook I'm refactoring into a series of smaller playbooks that get imported. Which is all well and good when importing them, but when testing them individually with e.g. vagrant the apt-cache often is stale and half my packages are missing.

I could of course put a task to update the apt-cache in every single one of them, but that seems wasteful.

Is there any conditional check for if a playbook is running inside another playbook or directly from the command line? Or check that the cache is in fact up-to-date in a globally-scoped var and condition based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or check that the cache is in fact up-to-date in a globally-scoped var and condition based on that

You can very easily declare you are running in vagrant through the `Vagrantfile` (if you are using the ansible "provisioner"), through a static fact in `/etc/ansible/facts.d`, by expending the energy to declare an extra-var on the command line, by checking for the NIC vendor that corresponds to the VM (so VBox in my case), or the virtualization method, or or or.

Separately, you are also welcome to actually declare a "staleness" threshold, and run `apt-get update` if the mtime for `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` is older than some number of seconds/minutes/etc, which actually sounds much closer to what you really want versus having things behave one way in Vagrant and a separate way for real.

Comment: The last thing you suggested is what I want, but if I stat `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` and then run apt-update the mtime doesn't change?

Comment: So it looks like I was in the right ballpark, but just happened to choose the wrong file -- I blame having too small of a sample size. `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` does update every time I run `apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Matthew L. Daniel's excellent answer which I've accepted, here's the actual tasks:

```
tasks:
  - name: Get the apt-cache stat
    stat: path=/var/lib/apt/lists/partial
    register: cachage

  - name: Update apt cache
    apt: update_cache=yes
    when: '{{ (ansible_date_time.epoch|float - cachage.stat.mtime) > 1800.0 }}'
```